# Protege inconsistent ontologies warning

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

Followed this intro youtube.com/playlist?list=PLea0WJq13cnAfCC0azrCyquCN_tPelJN1 to create the ontology. It is a little reduced http://prntscr.com/bo4l3w and I added canBeTutor (meaning somebody can become tutor for somebody) object property on my own. As far as I understand, I can add SWRL rules and then launch reasoner to create new knowledge. So I added prntscr.com/bo4lk7 . I started Hermit reasoner prntscr.com/bo4lqx . But obtained inconsistent ontologies warning prntscr.com/bo4lu0 . Clicked Explain button and got the following explanation http://prntscr.com/bo4lyg . My onto is here synoparser.ru/onto/protege.owl 
1. Could you please tell what that mean? 
2. Just for general understanding. I read that reasoner can create new knowledge. Does that mean just relations, or also individuals and classes? 
3. Where can I find readoner added knowledge in Protege 5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation in one of the figures you provided explains the inconsistency.  The ontology says that

- the classes Student and Lecturer and disjoint (that is, that no individual can be both a Student and Lecturer)
- the domain of studies is Student, which means that if x studies y, then x is a Student
- the domain of firstname is Lecturer, which means that if x firstname y, then x is a Lecturer

Now, since Student1 has firstname Andrew, Student1 must be a Lecturer. Since Student1 studies cs101, then Student1 must be a Student.  But Student and Lecturer are disjoint;  no individual can be both.  But Student1 is both.  That's an inconsistency.

Comment: Oh great it worked for me!!! Just changed firstname domain to Person. Still did not understand what "knowledge" are added after reasoner work, but it works)

Comment: Sorry, just didnt know how to consider) Ready!